# How can I source several files into my .bashrc?

Tags: bash, function

I want to write my Bash functions each in a separate file, for easier version control, and source the whole lot of them in my `.bashrc`.

Is there a more robust way than e.g.:

```bash
. ~/.bash_functions/*.sh
```

Comment: Define "robust".

Comment: @MichaelHomer, how about—won't break if the directory is missing, won't break if the directory is empty, won't provide huge amounts of noise if there are a lot of files in that directory without read permissions....

Comment: I do see your point, though, since if the functions/scripts are incorrectly/maliciously written it's not going to be "robust" in any meaningful way even if fulfills all of the above.  The above would be enough for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's simply a matter of surrounding it all with appropriate error checks:

```bash
fn_dir=~/.bash_functions
if [ -d "$fn_dir" ]; then
    for file in "$fn_dir"/*; do
        [ -r "$file" ] && . "$file"
    done
fi
```

Comment: What does the line that starts with [ -r "$file ] mean? Some explanation would be helpful.

Comment: It could be rewritten "`if [ -r "$file" ] ; then source "$file" ; fi`". On Unix systems, `[` is an alias (often a hardlink) to `/bin/test`, a program that evaluates its arguments and returns 0 or nonzero in response, which you can then react to in a script using either `if` or embedded `&&` type logic. It's a style choice, not a functional one. The one who edited my script thus feels it's better to be terse than verbose. You can argue over which is clearer, but both are correct.

Answer (score 1):

As for source multiple files at once, it can be done by creating a redirect of it's  concatenated output, like:

```bash
source <(cat ~/.bash_functions/*.sh)
```

As for the robust part you might need to have an error check properly set for whatever you're sourcing, such as:

```bash
source <(cat ~/.bash_functions/*.sh)||echo "ERROR: failed while sourcing $?";exit 1
```

here is another snippet, where you can also validate the sourced files it-self like:

```bash
sourced_files=$(source <(cat ~/.bash_functions/*.sh) 2>&1 > /dev/null)
if [ -n "$sourced_files" ]; then
 echo "ERROR: nonzero returned"
fi
```

Would be even better if possible to add an error validation inside whatever you're sourcing, with custom error codes so you can have a better track where it failed, such as:

```bash
err=0
...
...
# your shell script
...
some-command-i-wanna-check
if [ "$?" -ne 0 ];then
 echo "ERROR: my failed description"
 err=101
 exit $err 
fi
```

Comment: Definitely not the way to go. Unfortunately, I had to downvote.  No error checks make it a time-ticking bomb.

Comment: I've missed the robust part. I've edited the snippet addressing the "robustness"