# how can I use many .bashrc scripts?

Tags: bash, shell-script

(I have seen this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/270833/how-can-i-source-several-files-into-my-bashrc), but not sure, if it's the same)

I use a lot of `alias` in my `.bashrc` script.
Is there any way, to use many different `.bashrc` scripts?

for example
`git.bashrc`

```
alias gpull='git pull'
alias gcom='git commit -a -m '
alias gpush='git push'
alias gstat='git status'
alias gco='git checkout'
```

`ide.bashrc`

```
alias idea='/home/myname/dev/ide/idea/bin/idea.sh'
alias idea='/home/myname/dev/eclipse/eclipse/bin/eclipse.sh'
```

normal `.bashrc` should include something like

```
include ide.bashrc
include git.bashrc
# normal stuff like:
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

I want to use version control to have them on all my computers, but I can't really use the complete bashrc file for it.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: `for rcfiles in git.bashrc ide.bashrc; do if [[ -e "$rcfiles" ]]; then source "$rcfiles"; fi; done` You need to add the absolute path for the rcfiles if needed. Maybe add the `-f` test also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The keyword for this is `source` (or simply `.`) instead of `include`.

Add this to your `.bashrc`:

```
# Include more scripts
source /path/to/ide.bashrc
source /path/to/git.bashrc
```

or

```
# Include more scripts
. /path/to/ide.bashrc
. /path/to/git.bashrc
```

or include all from one directory:

```
if [ -d /path/to/includes ]; then
    for f in /path/to/includes/*.bashrc; do
        . "$f"
    done
fi
```

Read:

- [What's the meaning of a dot before a command in shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114300/whats-the-meaning-of-a-dot-before-a-command-in-shell)
- [running script with ". " and with "source "](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17815/running-script-with-and-with-source)

Comment: I will read the stuff you mentioned, thanks a lot!